# Efficiently searching through a vincinity of a route using Open StreetMap and Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm trying to find a set of routes (or rather simple pairs (Point_1, Point_2) from a given set) that are within *n* km from the route i have already drawn. I have drawn said route using Leaflet Routing Api, and the set is built from pairs of (Langitude, Longtitude).

My problem is I don't want to search in radius of a point on the route but in *n* km from a route line on each side (see pic below). Let's assume that the red line is my route and black lines define the search area.

I'm struggling with coming up with some kind of efficiently doing that, rather than searching in circle each interval. Especially since both Point_1 and Point_2 must be in the search area.

[image: route]